# Using Masonry in Rails - boxes not moving on window resize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-masonry

I have tried this using both the files from the Masonry website, plus the masonry-rails gem, but am getting the same problem.

Basically, when I resize the browser window, the boxes aren't moving to fit the new page size. Instead, I'm just getting scroll bars appearing in the browser.

I know that the files are loading fine, and picking up the right selectors, because if I e.g. change the column width in the masonry() parameters, the boxes do appear in a different place when I load the page.

Also, I'm using Bootstrap if that's relevant, but I've named the selectors so they don't clash with the ones reserved for bootstrap - e.g. using #masonry-container instead of #container.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!!

application.js:

```
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
```

message_board/show:

```
<div id="show-message-board">
    <%= render :partial => "show_message_board", :locals => { :messages => current_user.messages }, :remote => true %>  
</div>


<script>
$(function(){
  $('#masonry-container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.item',
    columnWidth : 50,
    isAnimated: true
  });
});


</script>
```

_show_message_board.html.erb:

```
<div id="masonry-container" class="transitions-enabled infinite-scroll clearfix">
<% messages.each do |message| %>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="message_from"><%= message.user.first_name %> <%= message.user.last_name %>:</p>
    <p class="message_content"><%= message.content %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

EDIT:

I've tried using the following as suggested elsewhere, and that still doesn't work!:

```
$(function(){
    var $container = $('#masonry-container');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.item'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have a closing </div> in the _show_message_board.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get Masonry to work in my Rails project.  Perhaps this will help you...

1. I downloaded the "jquery.masonry.min.js" file from the site and placed it in my app\assets\javascripts directory.
2. I added
   `//= require jquery.masonry.min` to my application.js file
3. I created a separate css file for masonry (just to keep things neat) called "masonry.css.scss" under my app\assets\stylesheets directory.  This is the CSS I have (I'm using "box" instead of your "item"): 

   `.box {
     margin: 5px;
     padding: 5px;
     background: #D8D5D2;
     font-size: 11px;
     line-height: 1.4em;
     float: left;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     display: inline;
     width: 260px;
   }`

   .box img {
     width: 100%;
   }
4. Since I'm using the code in my "home\index.html.erb" file, I created a "home.js" file under my app\assets\javascripts" directory.  This is the js code I have:

`jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var $container = $('#UserShoppingRequestsContainer');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector:'.box',
                isAnimated:true,
                animationOptions:{
                    duration:750,
                    easing:'linear',
                    queue:false
                }
            });
        });
    })`

1. Finally, in my "home\index.html.erb" file, I have something like this:

   ```
    <div id="UserShoppingRequestsContainer">
       <% @shopping_requests.each do |shopping_request| %>
          <div class="box col3" id="<%= shopping_request.id.to_s %>">
             <%= link_to image_tag(shopping_request.request_picture.url(:medium)),                    user_shopping_request_path(shopping_request.user, shopping_request) %>
             <p class="serif1_no_padding"><%= shopping_request.category.name %></p>
          </div>
       <% end %>
    </div>
   ```

I think that's it.